# Is there a better way to group query results with a loop in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

that´s my first question in **stackoverflow**.

I have two MYSQL tables: categories and products. I manage the query results with a while loop in PHP to group every category with its products. It´s the first time I do something so, and I think I made it very "crafty/hardcoded" (Sorry for my English). I think that should be a better way to do this. So, I´d like to ask to professional programmers. Here is my code:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `name` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `name` text NOT NULL,
 `description` text NOT NULL,
 `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `photo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=33 ;
```

I have a query that returns products relationed with their category:

```
SELECT categories.name as category,products.name as product
FROM categories
INNER JOIN products ON(categories.id = products.category)
```

With PHP I manage the results to create an unordered list for every category with its products:

```
<?php
$category = '';//A control variable

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    //if its a new category I start a new <ul>
    if($row['category'] != $category)
    {
        //If it´s not the firt category I need to close previous one
        if($category != '')
        {
            echo "</ul>\n";
        }
        //I start the new <ul>
        echo '<h2>' . $row['category'] . '</h2>';
        echo '<ul>';
    }

    //I create the correspondient <li>
    echo '<li>' . $row['product'] . "</li>\n";

    //Asign the value of actual category for the next time in the loop
    $category = $row['category'];

}

//I neeed to close last <ul>
echo "</ul>\n";
?>
```

Is there a better way to do this operation?
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: You might want to do an order by on the category name, to ensure that they are all together.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I haven´t specify it because that sql returns results ordered by categories.name. If it wouldn´t do so, I couldn´t construct the ul as I want.

Comment: the statement as is cannot guarantee that it returns things ordered, if you leave it like that you can unexpectedly find your code broken later when sql returns a different sequency where not all categories are grouped together. Better is to add the order by to ensure there won't be any problems later.

Comment: Thanks. I added it after James Black´s comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always best not to mix HTML with PHP.

Since you wanted my advice (veteran PHP coder of some 12 years), I'll just code it from scratch real fast:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$sql = "SELECT categories.name as category,products.name as product
FROM categories
INNER JOIN products ON(categories.id = products.category)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$categories = array();
while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
{
    $category = $row['category'];
    $categories[$category][] = $row['product'];
}

// In your view:
?>
<html>
    <body>
<?php
    foreach ($categories as $category => $products)
    {
?>
        <h2><?php echo $category; ?></h2>
        <ul class="products">
<?php
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
?>
            <li><?php echo $product; ?></li>
<?php
        }
?>
        </ul>
<?php
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and your advice. I think it´s the exact answer for my question: create an array with the results and open it with a foreach().
The link given by premiso about Hierarchical Data it´s very usefull too.

Comment: Could you also vote up my answer? it helps my reputation.  thanks, bro.

Comment: Also, please avoid nesting HTML in PHP wherever possible.  It's **ok** and even **preferable** to embed **logic-free** code in an HTML template, but **totally wrong** to embed business logic in a view.  E.g. if you ever find yourself doing much more than outputting text in a view, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I tried to vote up your answer, but I cant due to still haven´t 15 of reputation. Asap I have 15 I´ll vote it up.
Thanks for the advice. I´ll keep it in mind. I actually work with CodeIgniter, and I´m trying to keep my views as clean as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading into [Hierarchical Data](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). A great read. You should particularly pay attention to the Nested Set Model.

It does take a bit to learn and also takes a bit to implement, but is well worth it for the end result!

Comment: Wow, I didn´t know I was in a so complex situation!
Thanks for the link. It will be very usefull for me to learn more about databases, the nested set model and the implementation of data with tree structure.

Comment: we use that same hierarchal approach where i work, and it's by no means easy.  But the alternatives are even worse.  Unlimited-nested categories and multi-parent nodes are very complicated beasts.

Comment: Yea, it is not easy at all, especially when adding / creating items. But once the system is in place it is 10x easier and more efficient than the alternative. It is worth reading up on to gain the knowledge at any rate :)

Comment: If you would like to drop a hyperlink, you can simply add it as a comment under the question.  This is not an answer on StackOverflow.